# How to generate SQL schema from Spring Boot entities?

Tags: database, spring-boot, flyway

Spring Boot is a good framework to develop quickly applications. However, when creating an application binded to database, it seems some of the work must be done twice (I'm using Flyway):

- create table creation SQL queries scripts
- create Spring entites containing corresponding annotations
- run application : the flyway script generates the tables

Writing scripts AND entites can be time consuming, and without added value. Is it possible to do it only once?

Thanks

Comment: You can generate the database by using the appropriate Hibernate properties. However, this is only suitable for a development environment, not for actual production use (there is a possibility to update a DB with Hibernate ddl generation, but i wouldn't trust it in a real production environment). Also, by writing migration scripts, you can much better influence the migrations itself, even with value conversions etc.)

Comment: spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

Answer (score 15):

Just set theese properties on your configuration file:

```
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-source=metadata
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action=create
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-target=create.sql
```

The schema file will be generated automatically in the project root. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use JPA Buddy plugin. It has a "Show DDL" menu where you can visualize the sql script for a selected entity. Really useful when you want to avoid creating everything manually.